# Set default value in TextBoxFor when type = file

Tags: asp.net-mvc, filepath, html.textboxfor

I am using an `@Html.TextBoxFor` to load and, potentially, set an attachments file path on an edit page. I can get the file browser window to open and reset the value. However, I cannot get the current, or default, value to load with the page. Here is the syntax I'm using right now:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => item.Filepath, new { @value = item.Filepath, @type = "file" })
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm to understand the question correctly, it appears that you are trying to set the default value of the file path to open. The short answer is that you can't do this. The reason being that if you were able to set the file path in code, you could set the path maliciously to something you wanted to steal from the users machine, and dynamically submit the post via client side code. The user must explicitly say where he wants to browse to. This is a security feature.

Comment: No, I want the current value in the database to appear in the text box.

Comment: This is possible to accomplish, and I know because I had it set to do so. However, after working with a coworker on another aspect of this page, the code was deleted and since i had not promoted I could not recover it.

Comment: The file input type creates a field through which users can upload files from their local computer or network. The VALUE attribute specifies the name of the initial file, but it is typically ignored by browsers as a security precaution.  from:  http://htmlhelp.com/reference/html40/forms/input.html